# Trying to use getElementsByClass in VB.NET..?

Tags: vb.net, browser, invoke, getelementsbyclassname

I keep getting this error when trying to implement getElementsByClassName..

```
Error   1   'getElementsByClassName' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'.
```

I'm trying to press a button on webbrowser1 by doing:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByClassName("search-button").InvokeMember("submit")
```

Any tips?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution and can use:

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    If InStr(curElement.GetAttribute("classname").ToString, "search-button") Then
        curElement.InvokeMember("Click")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

at `GetAttribute("classname")` use for class and `GetAttribute("id")` use for id

Test on VS2008 to VS2017 it working

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), which you get out of the `WebBrowser.Document` property has a `getElementsByClassName` method you can invoke.

I think your options are:

1. If you know the Id, you can call [GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) and then `InvokeMember` against that, for example: `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("searchButtonId").InvokeMember("submit")`
2. If you know the tag name, you can call [GetElementByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx) and then iterate through this to find the element of the relevant class and then `Invoke Member` against that.

   If you look at the code sample, you'll see a `elem.GetAttribute("content")` call - you'll probably want to do something similar but with `elem.GetAttribute("class")` and inspect what gets returned to make sure it's the class name you want
3. Use the [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like has been referenced in another answer, but I think you have to iterate through and check each element using `GetAttribute` like referenced in point **(2)**

Comment: You can do that in javascript though